# My scraper fails to grab few contents

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script using `python` in combination with `re` module to parse some content from a webpage. The content I wish to parse: some of them have whitespaces around and some don't. How can I include them all in a single pattern. The one I tried can only grab which have whitespaces around. I used positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to get them.

I wanna grab the text `asked` from the below `html elements` using regex.

```
import re

content = """
<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-08 09:43:08Z" class="relativetime">2 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">asked<span title="2018-07-07 17:17:07Z" class="relativetime">18 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-06 20:35:48Z" class="relativetime">yesterday</span>
    </div>
"""
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=user-action-time">\s)(.*)(?=<span)')
for item in pattern.finditer(content):
    print(item.group())
```

Answer (score 1):

In my example I extracted the text contents of the entire div and how to just extract the contents of the span inside of the div. I would suggest using some kind of HTML parser. I used lxml html in my example but there are many others out there.

```
from lxml import html

content = """
<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-08 09:43:08Z" class="relativetime">2 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">asked<span title="2018-07-07 17:17:07Z" class="relativetime">18 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-06 20:35:48Z" class="relativetime">yesterday</span>
    </div>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(content)

user_action_times = [e.text_content() for e in tree.iter('div') if e.get('class') == 'user-action-time']
relative_time = [e.text_content() for e in tree.iter('span') if e.get('class') == 'relativetime' and e.get('title') is not None]

print (user_action_times)
print (relative_time)
```

Comment: If it was about grabbing them using `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` parser, I could have handled them myself and I would use them as question `tag`. I'm trying to learn regex. Hope you understand. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: My bad, I was just confused as to why you would want to use regex to parse HTML but if you are trying to learn regex that is a different story! Should I just delete this answer then?

Comment: No, you should not because someone might get help from your approach If he tries using a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to capture one word from the string, namely "asked", the following should work if you're consistently looking to grab one word

**INPUT (in the print statement at the bottom)**

```
import re
content = """
<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-08 09:43:08Z" class="relativetime">2 hours 
ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">asked<span title="2018-07-07 17:17:07Z" 
class="relativetime">18 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-06 20:35:48Z" 
class="relativetime">yesterday</span>
    </div>
"""


print(re.findall('<div[\S\s]*?>[\s]*([\S]+?)[\s<]+', content))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['asked', 'asked', 'asked']
```

.

.

Now if you needed to capture a sentence, you have to do a little finagling with the regex (the one I'm using is dirty, but effective -- again there may be some slight nuances depending on the content string which may affect its performance)

**INPUT SENTENCES (in the print statement at the bottom)**

```
import re
content = """
<div class="user-action-time">
          asked my friend <span title="2018-07-08 09:43:08Z" 
class="relativetime">2 hours 
ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">asked my dad<span title="2018-07-07 17:17:07Z" 
class="relativetime">18 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">  asked my mom <span title="2018-07-07 17:17:07Z" 
class="relativetime">18 hours ago</span>
    </div>

<div class="user-action-time">
          asked <span title="2018-07-06 20:35:48Z" 
class="relativetime">yesterday</span>
    </div>
"""


print(re.findall('<div[\S\s]*?>[\s]*([\S\s]+?[\S])[\s]*[<]+', content))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['asked my friend', 'asked my dad', 'asked my mom', 'asked']
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've made it myself. This is what i tried to get them:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=user-action-time">)(\s*?.*)(?=<span)')
for item in pattern.finditer(content):
    print(item.group().strip())
```

Output:

```
asked
asked
asked
```